# Indexing and crawling issue

Tags: indexing

Does anyone have any idea about this, my website has around 200k pages but indexing is only for 6k pages for a long time. However, the sitemaps are also updated, how can I increase indexing pace, because there is no improvement in traffic and visibility for a long time. The domain is https://www.tradebrio.com/ Anyone can check and tell if there is any blockage somewhere.

Thank you in advance. Your little help will be very helpful for me.

I've tested GSC, GA, etc.